# Does the Mac Pro 2008 display memory speeds accurately in System Information?

Tags: macos, mac, hardware, memory, mac-pro

Can anyone confirm that when a [Mac Pro 2008](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/stats/mac-pro-eight-core-2.8-2008-specs.html) has 800MHz FB-DIMMs installed it displays the Ram speed as 800Mhz in the System Information and not 667MHZ. I am running OS X Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified that there was only PC2 - 5300 RAM installed, which is 667MHZ. So there was not any 800MHZ ram installed, so I can verify that 667MHZ was in fact accurate in this situation.